# Python nested dictionaries into reStructuredText bullet list

Tags: python, dictionary, restructuredtext

I have this dictionary:

```
d = {'B': {'ticket': ['two', 'three'], 'note': ['nothing to report']}, 'A': {'ticket': ['one'], 'note': ['my note']}, 'C': {'ticket': ['four'], 'note': ['none']}}
```

and I'm trying to convert it into a .rst document as a bullets list, like:

```
* A

  * ticket:

    * one

  * note

    * my note

* B

  * ticket:

    * two
    * three

  * note:

    * nothing to report

* C

  * ticket:

    * four

  * note:

    * none
```

I read [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347505/what-are-some-approaches-to-outputting-a-python-data-structure-to-restructuredte) but I cannot *translate* it into a bullet list

Thanks to all

Comment: Did you try with a template manager? Another (correlated) problem: could be the depth (nesting grade) infinite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For something like your specific example, what about this:

```
>>> for key, value in d.items():
...    print('* {}'.format(key))
...    for k, v in value.items():
...       print(' * {}:'.format(k))
...       for i in v:
...         print('  * {}'.format(i))
...
* B
 * note:
  * nothing to report
 * ticket:
  * two
  * three
* A
 * note:
  * my note
 * ticket:
  * one
* C
 * note:
  * none
 * ticket:
  * four
```

Comment: Thanks your solution is great and it works fine. To save the file I just added: `f = open("path_to_rst", 'w')` and replaced `print` with `f.write`. I have a small problem with indentation and blank lines. Even if I add `\n` after each `{}` the output files does not contains empty lines (as in the question). This could be a problem for future `rst2....` commands

Comment: solved by adding a custom `f.write("\n")` line within the code. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

A more of less generic solution to your problem would be a recursive function:

```
def bullet_list(elements, level=0, indent_size=4):
    try:
        items = elements.items()
    except AttributeError:
        for bullet_point in elements:
            yield '{}* {}'.format(' ' * (indent_size * level), bullet_point)
    else:
        for bullet_point, sub_points in items:
            yield '{}* {}'.format(' ' * (indent_size * level), bullet_point)
            yield from bullet_list(sub_points, level=level + 1, indent_size=indent_size)

for line in bullet_list(d):
    print(line)
```

outputs:

```
* A
    * note
        * my note
    * ticket
        * one
* C
    * note
        * none
    * ticket
        * four
* B
    * note
        * nothing to report
    * ticket
        * two
        * three
```

​Note however that the ordered is not guaranteed in dictionaries until very recent versions of python.

Comment: Great. I will try to manage this function an adapt it to the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ugly and dirty

```
def bullet(d, depth=1):
    for k,v in d.items():
       print(''.join([depth * ' ', '* ', k]))
       if isinstance(v, dict):
           bullet(v, depth+1)
       else:
           for e in v:
                print(''.join([depth * ' ', ' * ', e]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would break the task down into three steps:-

1 - Sort the dictionary - as this is impossible it would be best to create a list of keys, sort this list then iterate through them

2 - Check if ticket exists and the for item in ticket to print them

3 - Check if note exists then print each item for note.