# Modifying a reStructuredText (reST) documents using Python

Tags: python, parsing, restructuredtext

I would like to know how to modify reStructuredText ([reST](https://wiki.python.org/moin/reStructuredText)) documents using Python.

I assume that the proper way to do it is to parse the reST document, modify it and write it back as reST.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883428/how-to-parse-restructuredtext-in-python) there is a description for parsing a reST document using [Docutils](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/).

With the code in that answer I can get a parsed document, unfortunately it seems that [there is not docutils writer](https://github.com/docutils/docutils/tree/master/docutils/docutils/writers) for turn back the intermediate representation to reST.

How can I accomplish this?

Please, note that I don't need it to be done with Docutils, it's just that it seems the most obvious option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347505/what-are-some-approaches-to-outputting-a-python-data-structure-to-restructuredte

Comment: @match I don't need to turn a python data structure into reST, I want to modify, using python, existing reST documents.

Comment: Your question is too broad. You need to provide at least an example of the original reST and the desired output reST. You could also look into [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/).

Comment: You may not need to parse the entire doc if you are just trying to perform some localized transformations. But as-is without actual examples, your question is too broad.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Is there a reST Writer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804333/is-there-a-rest-writer)